# Resize Images without JLabel

Tags: java, swing

Im writing a River-Raid-Like game, and all images are drew with g.drawImage(...).
My question is: How to keep the content aspect ratio, and scale the content to fit the new window size ,when someone will resize the JFrame?

Is there any option like that? Can i do this without using JLabels and Layouts? If not, how to do this other way?

My code to draw things on the JPanel

```
 private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawStrings(g2);
        mapa.drawMap(g2);
        ArrayList ms = craft.getMissiles();

        for (Object m1 : ms) {
            Missile m = (Missile) m1;
            g2.drawImage(m.getImage(), m.getX(), m.getY(), this);
        }
        g2.drawImage(craft.getImage(), craft.getX(), craft.getY(), this);
        for (EnemyJet enemy : enemies) {
            g2.drawImage(enemy.getImage(), enemy.getX(), enemy.getY(), this);
        }
        for (Fuel fuel : fuels) {
            g2.drawImage(fuel.getImage(), fuel.getX(), fuel.getY(), fuel.getHeight(), fuel.getHeight(), this);
        }
        for (Obstacle o : obst) {
            g2.drawImage(o.getImage(), o.getX(), o.getY(), this);
        }
        drawStrings(g2);
    }
```

Also Jpanel constructor:

```
  private void initBoard() {
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        craft = new Craft(ICRAFT_X, ICRAFT_Y);
        mapa = new Mapa();
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        initEnemiesAndAddThem();
        czas = new Timer(delay, this);
        czas.start();
    }
```

JFrame constructor:

```
 private void initGame()
    {
        add(new Plansza());
        setTitle("Reeevah Raaid");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        //setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        //setResizable(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the entire thing:

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    AffineTransform originalTransform = g2.getTransform();
    g2.scale(getWidth() / (double) WIDTH, getHeight() / (double) HEIGHT);

    // Do all drawing here

    g2.setTransform(originalTransform);
}
```

Some notes:

- The `g2.setTransform(originalTransform)` at the end is important.  The Graphics object does not belong to you—it may be used to draw other components, so you need to leave it in the same state it had when it was given to you.
- WIDTH and HEIGHT need to be cast to double, because in Java, if any operand of a division operation is a double, the result is double, but if they are both int, integer division is performed, which is definitely not what you want.  (For instance, `3 / (double) 2` is 1.5, but `3 / 2` is exactly 1.)

Comment: sorry to say, but it's not working since scale can be very very big or too small because there is only a background visible, but the intersection occur which proves that they are visible somewhere (the images). I like this approach because it works for all images in do drawing but finally something is wrong with the scale

Comment: EDIT: After some research, intersetcion occurs but no images are visible... I tired to multiply the scale by 0.5 or 2 to see if it makes images too small or too big that i cant see them but they are invisible...

Answer (score 0):

Any image needs to be drawn as follows:

```
  double fct=1.0*image.getWidth()/getWidth();
  double fct2=1.0*image.getHeight()/getHeight();
  if(fct2>fct) fct=fct2;
  g2.drawImage(image, x, y, (int)(1.0*image.getWidth()/fct), (int)(1.0*image.getHeight()/fct), this);
```

This will leave a lot of empty area - but that is if you want to keep the aspect ratio.

--

To center the image you do the following:

```
int newWidth=(int)(1.0*image.getWidth()/fct);
int newHeight=(int)(1.0*image.getHeight()/fct);
g2.drawImage(image, getWidth()/2-newWidth()/2, getHeight()/2-newHeight()/2, newWidth, newHeight, this);
```

Comment: Works good, since it actually resizes the visual part. There is a problem with rectangular bounds that i take from the image, they aren changed. Can you tell how to make it?

Comment: also, the content is floated left, can you tell how to center the jpanel?